# How do I target an NPC when using console commands?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am trying to use the `OpenActorContainer 1` console command.  Most of the threads I've seen say to "click" or "highlight" the NPC whose inventory you wish to access.  However, when I click on them, the only thing my character does is draw his weapon.

How do I select an NPC?

Answer (score 12):

You have to click on them while the console is open. Then type the command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: just to add to this, sometimes you may click on the wrong object, most often you'll have to be fairly close to the target in order for your click to register properly.

Answer (score -3):

Open the console commands ~ then you click on the NPC/object type in command for example tgm click enter then command will be executed.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer, and is 6 years late.